# invoke vs. evoke vs. inquire

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, verbs, synonyms

> **invoke vs. evoke vs. inquire**

Which one of the followings is the best English?

(1) We have invoked three questions in this article and have addressed them with certain depths.

(2) We have evoked three questions in this article and have addressed them with certain depths.

(3) We have inquired three questions in this article and have addressed them with certain depths.

Or, how to modify it to be the best English? Many thanks! :)

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to convey.  Are you *mentioning* three questions asked prior?  Are you *posing* three questions that you then answer?  I don't believe any of your usages are to be found in common parlance.

Answer (score 1):

First: “invoke” and “evoke” have two different meanings.

> **in·voke**
>   
>  <sup>*inˈvōk*</sup>
>    <sup>verb</sup>
>   
> cite or appeal to (someone or something) as an authority for an action or in support of an argument.
>   
> *“the antiquated defense of insanity is rarely invoked today”*
>
> synonyms: cite, refer to, adduce, instance; 
>       call on (a deity or spirit) in prayer, as a witness, or for inspiration.
>
> synonyms: appeal to, pray to, call on, supplicate, entreat, solicit, beg, implore; 
>       call earnestly for.
>   
> *“she invoked his help against this attack”*
> <sub>Source: [Oxford Dictionaries, definition of “invoke”](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/invoke)</sub>

versus:

> **e·voke**
>   
>  <sup>*iˈvōk*</sup>
>    <sup>verb</sup>
>   
> 1. bring or recall to the conscious mind.
>   
> *“the sight of American asters evokes pleasant memories of childhood”*
>
> synonyms: bring to mind, put one in mind of, conjure up, summon (up), invoke, elicit, induce, kindle, stimulate, stir up, awaken, arouse, call forth, elicit (a response).
>   
> *“the awkward kid who evoked giggles from his sisters”*
>
> synonyms: appeal to, pray to, call on, supplicate, entreat, solicit, beg, implore; 
>       call earnestly for.
>   
> *“she invoked his help against this attack”*
> <sub>Source: [Oxford Dictionaries, definition of “evoke”](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/evoke)</sub>

Perhaps a better way to say it is as follows:

"We have addressed three questions in this article."

Answer (score 1):

We have asked three questions in this article, and addressed each with a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, I think

```
We have posed three questions in this article and have addressed them with certain depths.
```

would make the most sense.